# Batteries in parallel and series. Auto disconnect load while charging

Tags: batteries, mosfet, parallel, series

New to designing circuits and PCBs. I'm working on a project and I can't seem to figure out how exactly how to do what I'm trying to do. I'm hoping one of you can give me a hand understanding the concept behind a few things I just can't seem to wrap my head around.

Basically, I'm designing a PCB for something that is battery powered but it's in a really tight space so it can't be removed for charging, it has to be charged in its spot. I have some 3.7v 18650 batteries that I am charging off of a TP4056. The batteries are constantly connected to their load and so I need to make a circuit that disconnects their load when the 5v is applied for charging. I'm told a MOSFET will do what I'm thinking but I can't seem to figure out exactly how.

The batteries are in groups of 3, 2 groups per each PCB. They're wired in series to get to 11.1v and in parallel with all the other groups to get me to the current I need. The plan is to charge each battery individually by being wired to the charger in parallel on a different PCB layer. I also threw in an LED as a charging indicator.

Ultimately this is a much larger design and this circuit has to be repeated 4 more times. (I need to fit this design in a pipe that is only 1.25" in diameter so it's about 7.5" total length after connecting (5) 18" PCBs.

Any advice is appreciated! Here's a picture of what I'm thinking will work:

[image]

Comment: Use a micro-switch to capture the presence of the connector...

Comment: I don't think I have space for one near the connector, it's going to be a very tight fit.

Comment: The circuit you show won't work, as it shorts all (most of?) the cells.  You would need a large number of switches to change the cell connections from serial to parallel.

Comment: Normally, the longer lline in the cell symbol is the positive terminal - you've used it as negative, which will confuse the more experienced viewers.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the negative, i'll make that change.

Comment: As for the switches you mention, could I do it with a MOSFET per each battery (or would it be per terminal of each battery?) or are you thinking an SSR would be better (if I can fit them)?

Comment: Batteries BT2, BT3, BT5 and BT6 are shorted in your schematics. Is this a kind of joke?

Answer (score 1):

Wiring batteries in parallel for charging and series for discharging sounds OK if you say it quickly. However it's best to avoid it, and do things 'normally', which is to keep them wired in series and charge and discharge in series, with appropriate balancing, and a boost converter between charge source and batteries to make the required charge voltage.

[Your drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Seopn.jpg) shows the batteries wired in series *and* parallel, which shorts most of them. The multi-way relay needed to switch them between series and parallel would take a lot of space, consume power, stop the ability to use while charging, limit the discharge current, and is an extra point of potential failure.

Comment: What if I had a TP4056 per battery? The batteries would still be in (2) groups of (3) in series and those two groups would be in parallel but that should avoid shorting, right?

Comment: Something like this: https://imgur.com/a/3h8K9

Comment: The problem with these 'easy' series parallel schemes is you tie yourself in knots. BT14  -ve is tied to BT13 and 15 +ve. BT14 +ve is tied to both BT13 and 15 -ve. See if you can figure out which way the current is going to flow. See if you can figure out why, in this commercial universe of smart people, you don't see parallel charge series discharge battery packs anywhere.

Comment: Gotcha. Yea that won't work. What if every side of each battery had a mosfet acting as a switch that disconnects or connects it to the batteries and/or charger? Is that possible?

Comment: Keep digging! It's sort of possible, and honestly not worth it once you've done it.

Comment: @Cadmium685 You could try it this way, it's a way I myself have thought of trying. Connect the cells permanently in series. Put a single cell charge controller on each cell. Construct a multi-output isolated supply, so each cell's charger gets its own power supply.